# How to attach an URL to an image

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried different ways to display a picture in my rails app,and when the user clicks on that he should be redirected to the URL i specify.

I tried this method,"rails method"

```
<li <%= link_to new_gig_path %><%= image_tag 'v.png' %></li>
```

and just the image was showing,but the image wasn't clickable.

than i tried this"HTML method" `<a href="the redirect url"><img src="link to an image"/></a>`

And it worked as i wanted,the image appeared,and when i clicked on it,it redirected where i wanted.The problem is that it is wrapped in `<a></a>` tags,but i need the code to be wrapped in `<li></li>` tags,

**note**:I also tried to wrap the `<a></a>` tags in `<li></li>` tags but it destroyed my design,i do need it to be just in `<li>` tags

looking into my navigation bar,you see that my nav-bar is structured in `<li>`tags

```
#instead of this comment I want to put the code,i am asking help with
<li><%= link_to '+Add Box', new_gig_path, id: "addgig" %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Edit Profile',edit_user_registration_path, id: "menu-overwritten" %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, id: "menu-overwritten"%></li>
```

More info:
Also i tried this method

```
<li><a href="url link to redirect"><img src="a link to an image" height="30" width="159" ></a></li>
```

This time it worked as well,but i don't think it is gonna be responsive if i leave this method.This is definitely not the rails way.
*Thank you.*

Comment: If I understand correctly you need your HTML to be like `<li><img /></li>`. If it is like `<li><a><img /></a></li>` it wont work for you?

Comment: `<li><a><img /></a></li>` works great,but it destroys my layout,because it contain a `<a>` tag,look at my **More Info**,in the end of the question,my last method,which worked,but i think it is the wrong way,for the long run.

Comment: I believe that the preferred way is to use `<li><a><img /></a></li>` and try to fix the layout. But if fixing the layout is a lot of work, I could only think a workaround with JavaScript. Are you looking for a HTML-only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li>
  <%= link_to new_gig_path  do %>
    <%= image_tag 'v.png', class: 'your-class' %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: To adjust the image,i would need to edit the css,how can i add an id or class to your code? thank you